# Speechkit Match - O - linker Error ios 8.1 xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, speech-to-text

I'm trying to convert speech to text using Speechkit framework.
But I'm getting Match -O - linker error all the time. I've tried all means to remove it - like adding all dependencies , removing and adding the framework, Changing simulator etc.
I've attached a screenshot and link to the my source code.![enter image description here][1]

Screenshot - 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6rcvq1hwf63k6qo/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-25%20at%2010.20.22%20am.png?dl=0

Link to the code - https://www.dropbox.com/s/9f2uje6p3rfyyz8/DragonMobileRecognizer.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

The SDK you downloaded is not consistent. You use latest headers but the SpeechKit library itself seems obsolete and it does not contain SpeechKitDelegate symbols as it should be.

You can download latest SDK from Nuance website, it should contain delegate.

Alternatively, you can continue using older version but you need to update headers to match and remove SpeechKitDelegate from your sources.

To check if library contains symbol you can use `nm` tool and `grep`.